# Hibernate saving Collection

Tags: hibernate

Is that possible to save a collection of object by itself?
I know how to save a collection of an object if it's in one-to-many relationship. Is there a way to save a collection of an object by itself since I don't wanna iterate it?

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from SQL way how we are doing multiple insertion

- Start transaction
- Create insert scripts for each and every record
- Run all the insert scripts in one transaction
- Commit transaction

In the same way if you want to insert from hibernate framework

- Create session
- Open transaction
- Create a for loop which in turn creates entity object
- Save each entity on completion of each iteration in loop
- Commit transaction
- Close the session

For hibernate side only when you commit all the transactions the SQL query for insert is generated. So it is not creating any overhead since you are using loop here. Hibernate don't have any inbuilt methods for your operation. You have to write custom insert method to satisfy your request

```
public void createList(List<C> list, Session session) 
{
    for (C obj : list)
    {
        session.save(obj);
    }
}
```